# Angular ngFor li html element set style

Tags: javascript, css, angular

```
<ul class="days">
    <liclass="day" *ngFor="let day of currentDays; let i = index"(click)="setStyle()">
        {{day}}
    </li> 
  </ul>
```

My question is how to add style to exactly specified element in list, when i use ngClass styles are added to all elements? It posible using method add pass reference to element and set style?

Comment: I think that you should use classes for everything in order to create the ability to change things in your style sheets.  That being said, based on a given iteration's property, you can assign it a particular class or set of classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can conditionally set using ngStyle. refer the following code.

```
<div [ngStyle]="{'background-color':isTrue === true ? 'green' : 'red' }"></<div>
```

Or refer the stackblitz link for another solution.

[enter link description here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngstyle-ngclass?file=app%2Fngstyle%2Fngstyle.component.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
<li [class.your-class]="expression">
```

For example:

```
<li [class.mat-elevation-z10]="i === selectedElement">
```

Or you can use `ngClass` with expressions

```
<li [ngClass]="{'first': true, 'second': true, 'third': false}">
```

Where `first`, `second` and `third` are your classes and `true`, `true`, `false` are the expressions.  In the example above, both first and second class would be applied.

Answer (score 0):

You can set different `class` to each `element`

```
<ul class="days">
    <li *ngFor="let day of currentDays; let i = index" [class]="'day'+(index+1)">
        {{day}}
    </li> 
  </ul>
```

in css set style to each one:

```
.day1{
...
}
```

Comment: tell for more help

Answer (score 0):

You can use ngClass itself with conditions. You can replace RequiredDay string with variable.

```
<ul class="days">
    <li [ngClass]="{'desiredClass':day === 'RequiredDay'}" *ngFor="let day of currentDays; let i = index" (click)="setStyle()">
       {{day}}
    </li> 
 </ul>
```